# Node get function doesn't return anything

Tags: node.js, websocket, ftp

I have this piece of code which uses jsftp to get the content of a file. It sometimes works and enters the get function and sometimes is skipped for reasons I don't know. I'm a newbie in Node (almost in programming), so it may be something stupid but I can't tell why it sometimes works and sometimes returns undefined.

```
if (newestName !== "") {
      var filePath = path + "/" + newestName;
      var str = ""; 
      jsFTP.get(filePath, (err, socket) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error");
          return;
        }

        socket.on("data", d => {
          str += d.toString();
          if (str.length > 0) {
            debugger;
            update(str);
            console.log("Sending: " + str);
          }
        });

        socket.on("close", err => {
          if (err) {
            console.error("There was an error retrieving the file.");
          } else {
            write();
          }
        });
        socket.resume();
      });
```

Update:
The code works finely if it's executed every second